# Gulp stream finishes before file is written

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, glob

Our build process runs our `app.js` through browserify to handle the `require()` statements, then concatenates the result with some other scripts to create `scripts.js`. This is done in two separate tasks.

For some reason the first task ends *before* it writes the files, causing `app.js` to be left out of the build. The task was copied from [this Gulp recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-with-globs.md) with minimal modifications.

Here are the relevant parts of our gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['angular', 'views-js'], function () {
  var bundledStream = through();

  bundledStream
      .pipe(source('app.js'))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(debug())
      .pipe(uglify())
      .on('error', gutil.log)
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write(paths.target))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target));

  globby([paths.scripts], function(err, entries) {
    if (err) {
      bundledStream.emit('error', err);
      return;
    }

    var b = browserify({
      entries: entries,
      debug: true,
    });

    b.bundle().pipe(bundledStream);
  });

  return bundledStream;
});

// Take all the scripts in the target directory and concatenate them to scripts.js.
gulp.task('scripts-all', ['scripts'], function () {
  return gulp.src([path.join(paths.target, '*.js'), '!'+path.join(paths.target, 'scripts.js')])
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
  .pipe(header(banner, { pkg : pkg } ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target))
  .pipe(livereload(reloadServer));
});
```

This is what happens when we build. Note that the `.debug()` pipe is executed *after* the task is finished. This causes the file to miss the `.src()` scan in `scripts-all`.

```
[16:57:46] Starting 'scripts'...
[16:57:46] Finished 'views' after 835 ms
[16:57:47] Finished 'scripts' after 749 ms
[16:57:47] Starting 'scripts-all'...
[16:57:47] gulp-debug: (2015-09-28 13:57:47 UTC)

File
cwd:      ~/projects/ourProject
base:     ~/projects/ourProject
path:     ~/projects/ourProject/app.js
contents: (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n...

[16:57:48] gulp-debug: end event fired (2015-09-28 13:57:48 UTC)
```

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `globby` but the documentation says it returns a promise. My guess is the promise will be resolved when it finishes and returns from the function you passed in. It may be you need to return the promise to keep the task from completing.

If that does not resolve this, I would try creating your own promise and resolving it in the `'end'` event handler for `bundledStream` since it looks like you want to resolve the task when `bundledStream` has finished its work.

```
var Q = require('q');

gulp.task('scripts', ['angular', 'views-js'], function () {
  var bundledStream = through();

  var deferred = Q.defer();

  bundledStream
      .pipe(source('app.js'))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(debug())
      .pipe(uglify())
      .on('error', gutil.log)
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write(paths.target))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target))
      .on('end', function()
        {
        deferred.resolve();
        });
....
  return deferred.promise;
```

I have not tested your particular task but this is how I handled a similar problem yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Globby's promise was resolved too early, because the rest of the toolchain was still not executed. We actually ended up fixing it by calling the gulp callback function at the end of the stream which should get us pretty much the same results as your suggestion.

Comment: Glad to hear to got it fixed. I haven't used the callbacks yet but I'll keep your solution in mind when I do.